# Creating a WCF JSON (non RESTful) Service

Tags: wcf, json, rest

I am trying to create a simple non-RESTful JSON service using WCF and .NET 4. 
I'd like my service to be able to parse a JSON request message with a specific format, something like this:

```
{ "MethodNameRequest": { "MethodParam1Name": "ParamValue1", "MethodParam2Name": "ParamValue2" } }
```

The endpoint for this service should reside in a single constant URI ("http://myserver/myservice/") so that all methods could be invoked using a POST request to it.

The problem is that whenever I try to declare two (or more) methods using the same "UriTemplate" and the same HTTP verb "POST" (using WebInvokeAttribute), like this:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "")]
public string Method1()
{
   return "Method1";
}

[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "")]
public string Method2()
{
   return "Method2";
}
```

I get the following exception:

> In contract '', there are multiple
>   operations with Method 'POST' and a
>   UriTemplate that is equivalent to ''.
>   Each operation requires a unique
>   combination of UriTemplate and Method
>   to unambiguously dispatch messages.
>   Use WebGetAttribute or
>   WebInvokeAttribute to alter the
>   UriTemplate and Method values of an
>   operation.

Any ideas on how I can configure WCF to allow this?

Comment: Show some code ...It's not clear from your question

Comment: Do you have any problem in changing the UriTemplate?

Comment: I don't want to. That's my point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how WCF could figure out which method to call if it somehow allowed the identical UriTemplate for the different methods. Seems you need to implement logic inside the method to handle content based processing.

Comment: That's a solution I'd like to avoid.
I figure that since WCF supports a "wrapped" request message body, it could maybe utilize it in order to differentiate between methods.

Comment: If it had the capability you want, then the WebInvoke attribute would need to have a parameter it would use to examine the request and determine which method to call but it doesn't. It only lets you configure the structure of the request & response messages.

Comment: The name of the method in the wrapped response message format matches the name of the method in the code, so why couldn't it be used in the request message as well, so that "Method2Request" would automatically be mapped to "Method2"?

Comment: I see your point, now you just need to convince the WCF team to add that capability :) Of course, you could just write your own implementation using the existing source code in the Mono project for WebInvokeAttribute. See the link below for the status of the System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute. It shows that it is fully implemented in the Mono 3.5 version. Mono is very code compatible with the official .NET Framework so you'll have a good start writing it. Link: http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=3.5&profile=2.0&assembly=System.ServiceModel.Web

Answer (score 0):

Try to ommit the `UriTemplate` property, use instead the `<enableWebScript/>` element in `web.config`. This will allow `wcf` to automatically handle the requests for you.